# Uncaught error in Pagespeed Insights on Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights

Have no clue what ghost-rider is... Error follows.

> Lighthouse returned error: generic::internal: Extension result empty.
>   Lighthouse calling Page.navigate with https://www.redacted.com/blog
>   Uncaught (in promise) Error: Extension timed out. No call to exit()
>   before render timeout. at wrs.Extension.onTimeout_
>   (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:5576:13) at
>   http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:708:9 at Map.forEach
>   () at chromium.DevTools.Connection.dispatchMessage
>   (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:707:76) at
>   chromium.DevTools.Connection.onJsonMessage_
>   (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:689:65) at :1:40

Comment: That looks pretty sketchy. You might have some malware.

Comment: This only happens to me when I analyze a URL with an embedded video from Facebook. Check if this is your case too.

Answer (score 0):

i agree it looks sketchy. i'm getting that same error when running pagespeed on my joomla test site. i grepped 'ghost-rider' on my server and full-text searched my db and can't find that anywhere on the site.

the url doesn't work and the domain ghost-rider is invalid of course.  no .com or anything.  weird...

running lighthouse on https://www.webpagetest.org/lighthouse gives a timeout after 80 seconds on my site (nothing about ghost-rider).  http://gtmetrix.com/ and sites like that seem to work fine and the site loads in about 6-10 secs.

ran an ispp scan and didn't find anything.

nothing else to add... anyone else getting this on pagespeed/lighthouse?